# Extract inner text from a div by id using an html string

Tags: php, preg-match, simple-html-dom

i have an html string with the following divs only:

```
<div id="title">My Title</div>
<div id="image">http://www.mpahmplakdjfe.co.uk/images/01.jpg</div>
<div id="fullcontent">In this div there are some html elements more</div>
```

I need to extract the inner text from divs "My title" etc.

how is it possible to do this with preg_match?

I tried the following (simple html dom) without luck:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($myhtml);
$ret = $html->find('div[id=title]')->innertext; (or outter) 
echo $ret;
```

Thanks !!!!

Comment: You never set `$myhtml` - you're on the right track though, don't use regex for this.

Comment: @pguardiario I do agree with you: she's _"on the right track"_; but _"don't use regex for this"_ is a non-productive advice imho. I can build this exact same function `find()->innertext` using regex and it'll be faster!

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html. This has been covered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('|<[^>]*title[^>]*>(.*?)<|', $html, $m);
```

will give you "My Title".

```
preg_match('|<[^>]*image[^>]*>(.*?)<|', $html, $m);
```

will give you "http//www.mpahmplakdjfe.co.uk/images/01.jpg".

```
preg_match('|<[^>]*fullcontent[^>]*>(.*?)<|', $html, $m);
```

will give you "some text here".

You can do it that way:

```
$html = '<div id="title">My Title</div>
<div id="image">http://www.mpahmplakdjfe.co.uk/images/01.jpg</div>
<div id="fullcontent">some text here</div>';

$m = array();
preg_match('|<[^>]*title[^>]*>(.*?)<|', $html, $m);
// inner text is in $m[1]
echo $m[1]; // == 'My Title'
```

If you want to get all inner text from the string, use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`:

```
// say you have that string
$html = '<div id="fullcontent"><div>hi</div><div>hello</div></div>';

$m = array();
preg_match_all('|>(?<innerText>[^<]*)<|', $html, $m);
echo count($m['innerText']); // 2     ;how many matches
echo $m['innerText'][0];     // == 'hi'
echo $m['innerText'][1];     // == 'hello'
```

[phpfiddle - http://x.co/6lbC6](http://x.co/6lbC6)

If you absolutely want inner texts only from `<div>`s, then you can modify `preg_match_all()` above like this:

```
preg_match_all('|<div[^>]*>(?<innerText>[^<]+)<|', $html, $m);
```

Comment: And if inside of a div there are more divs and html elements like: <div id="fullcontent"><div>hi</div><div>hello</div></div> how can i get them all? no matter what how many html elemets there are..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $subject = "<div id=\"image\">http://www.mpahmplakdjfe.co.uk/images/01.jpg</div>";

    preg_match("/<div id=\".*\">(.*)<\/div>/", $subject, $matches);

    print_r($matches[1]);
```

To understand the regex used in more detail:

https://regex101.com/r/tN6mD8/1

Regular expressions can look a little confusing in PHP as double-quotations have to be escaped. I always write mine in a separate editor first.

**Edit**: to get a specific tag:

```
    $subject = '<div id="image">http://www.mpahmplakdjfe.co.uk/images/01.jpg</div>';
    $title = '"image"';

    preg_match("/<div id=".$title.">(.*)<\/div>/", $subject, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I found solution by using regex.
[Here is the answer](https://regex101.com/r/IXDFth/1/) for your case:

```
\<div.*?\>(.*?)<\/div>
```